# Cannot check jquery ui checkbox based on values from angularjs model

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm using jQueryui [checkbox group](https://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/) to display three options to the user. I'm succesfully binding each of these checkboxes to an angular model, however I cannot get the checkboxes to check themselves if I change the model in the controller.

View

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div id="groupOptions">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test1" ng-model="testModel.item1" ng-checked="testModel.item1" /> Testing</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test2" ng-model="testModel.item2" ng-checked="testModel.item2" /> Testing 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test3" ng-model="testModel.item3" ng-checked="testModel.item3" /> Testing 3</label>
</div>
<pre>{{testModel|json}}</pre>
<script>
    $("#groupOptions").controlgroup();
</script>
```

angular module

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.testModel = {
    item1: true,
    item2: false,
    item3: false
  };
});
```

Notice that testModel.item1 is true, however checkbox test1 which is bound this this model is not checked.
Here is a [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/xDDROZaXmYvibvxaSLUT?p=preview)

I have also tried checked="testModel.item1" instead of ng-checked="testModel.item1" and that selects all the checkboxes no matter what the value is in the model/controller.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing jquery $(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#groupOptions").controlgroup();
});
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thank you